# PHP -> Pick value from two-dimensional array based on key

Tags: php, arrays

I need to pick a value based on a specific key from an two-dimensional array, how would I do that?

I only know the key of the second level in the array in my code, and not in which array key it sits in level 1...

example:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [1] => http://stackoverflow.com/
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => http://www.google.com
    )
    [2] => Array
    (
        [20567] => http://www.yahoo.com
    )
)
```

Now I would like to pick the value of the key 20567 dynamically, I don't know where it sits in level 1, could be 0, 1,2 or any other key.

I hope I explained that well enough :)

Comment: thanks for fixing the markup, don't quite get how to do that yet lol

Comment: Are these lives values? If so, is there a reason why this isn't a one-dimensional array?

Comment: those are live values yes, the reason it's two dimensions is that I use the keys in level 2 also, it's the value of the number of redirects a link has.

I did that so links with the same count of redirects overwrite the first key/value pair, so in the end I can simply pick it and redirect

Comment: sorry hit enter and couldn't edit the first comment...
That way I save 1 database query because the array will contain only unique keys and i don't have to check again which link has the number of redirects i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is: (should work)

```
function getURLbyRedirects($redirectNumber , $array)
{

 foreach($array as $lvl => $elems)
 {
   if(array_key_exists($redirectNumber , $elems))
     return $elems[$redirectNumber];
 }
 return false;
}
```

By the way , consider using a different structre for this array, something like this:

> Array (
>
> ```
> [0] => Array
>     (
>         [url] => http://stackoverflow.com/
>         [redirects] => 2067
>     )
> ```

Comment: Thanks that looks interesting too.

The problem I have with the structure you suggest is that if two links have the same number of redirects... In the end I'd like to pick the link with the lowest number of redirects, and I wouldn't know how to do that if I have multiple links with the same redirect count


The way I'm doing it, duplicate keys in level 2 get overwritten, so I end up with only one link that has the lowest number of redirects, and the link that was overwritten will be picked on the next run.

Comment: Well , you can apply a searching algorithem for the lowest value.
But if things go easier with your current structre - stick to it.

Comment: Nah, I meant if there are two or more of the same values :)
like for example:

link1 redirects: 20
link2 redirects: 20
link3 redirects: 21

Btw, picked your solution as it was the easiest for my case and does work very good.

Comment: In this case you should choose the first or the last one , after all it's not really matter , no?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [RecursiveArrayIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivearrayiterator.php) and [RecursiveIteratorIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php):

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array));

foreach ($iterator as $key => $value) {
    if ($key == 20567) {
        var_dump($value);
        break;
    }
}
```

Example in a function:

```
function valueForKey($array, $key) {
    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array));
    foreach ($iterator as $arrayKey => $arrayValue) {
        if ($arrayKey == $key) {
            return $arrayValue
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: @Marc: One advantage is that with this method it won't matter if your array has more levels in the future